# Non-Citizen of Canada entry to US via border

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, canada, borders

My brother lives in Canada and in the process of getting residency over there. He has another nationality and not very long ago has acquired B (not sure 1 or 2) visa to the US. He can go back and forth via airports without issues.

I'm a US citizen and we plan to go together to the US by car and I was wondering what he needs to do in order to avoid any issues when coming back to Canada.

As far as I know, he needs to tell Canadian authorities at the border that he's leaving before reaching the US checkpoint, and when going back he needs to tell US authorities the same thing. This is to have his passport stamped on both trips.

Is my knowledge on the matter correct? If not, what should be done to avoid any problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Long as he holds a valid passport with a US visa in it, like you state, there are no out of routine things expected on this border crossing.

Land or Air don't matter if the documentation is all in order.

> He can go back and forth via airports without issues.

Then he can also go via the land borders without any issues.

Comment: Okay thank you. The reason I asked is because I once saw a Korean woman having an issue when she returned to the US from Canada. She had valid visa to both countries, but she didn't explicitly visit the customs office on the US side before she left to Canada. They gave her some trouble and asked her to always inform them, in their office, before she leaves to Canada. I thought the process was similar.

Comment: @Everyone how long ago was that? Nowadays, Canada and the US report land entries to each other so they can be recorded as exits by the other country.

Comment: @phoog two years ago. Summer of 2017.